# Vue typescript props is dependent on another prop

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Using `<script setup lang="ts">`, how can I define a property that is dependent from another property?

Example: I want to require a variable if another variable is present.

I tried doing `defineProps<Props | PropsA>()`, but an error occurred. It says that **[@vue/compiler-sfc] type argument passed to defineProps() must be a literal type, or a reference to an interface or literal type.**

Answer (score 0):

You would use this syntax:

```
const props = defineProps<
myRequiredPropName: Props | PropsA
myOptionalPropName?: Props | PropsA
>()

// in your script/setup: props.myRequiredPropName
// in your template: myRequiredPropName
```

You cannot conditionally require a property and have the typescript compiler catch it.

Answer (score 0):

Imported types and complex ones are not supported for argument declaration type.

> As of now, the type declaration argument must be one of the following to ensure correct static analysis:

- A type literal
- A reference to an interface or a type literal in the same file

But you can use `PropType` utility :

```html
<script lang="ts" setup>

  const props = defineProps({
       propName:{
          type: Object as PropType<Type1 | Type2>
      }

   });
</script>
```